# wire:model no me actualiza las variables

Tags: laravel, eloquent, livewire

Mi problema surgió cuando agregue los métodos departamentos y municipios, me dejaron de funcionar wire:model, y si trataba de realizar un wire:click o wire:action me lanzaba 404 y el mensaje "No query result".

He intentado utilizando los hooks de update, e igualmente no me funcionan, creería que por lo mismo de que el wire:model no me actualiza mis variables.

De igual manera, siguiendo consejos en internet, de por ejemplo, usar wire:model.live me sucede nuevamente el error 404 y el mensaje "No query result"
Vista:

```
    <div>
        <div class="container mt-5">
            <fieldset>
                <legend><b> Formulario actualización de Clientes </b></legend>
            </fieldset>
            <div class="card p-4">
                <div class="mb-4">
                    <label for="search">Búsqueda de Cliente</label>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" wire:model="search" id="search" class="form-control">
                        <div class="input-group-append">
                            <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn btn-primary" type="button" wire:click="searchClient">
                                <i class="fas fa-search text-white"></i>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    {{ $search }}
                </div>
    
                {{-- Secciones Información y Dirección --}}
                <div class="mb-4 row">
                    {{-- Sección Información --}}
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <h3>Información</h3>
    
                        @if ($tipoPersona == 2)
                            <div class="mb-3">
                                <input type="text" wire:model="infoField2" id="infoField2" class="form-control" readonly>
                            </div>
                            <div class="mb-3">
                                <label for="infoField2" class="form-label">NIT</label>
                                <input type="text" wire:model="infoField2" id="infoField2" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                            <div class="mb-3">
                                <label for="nrc" class="form-label">NRC</label>
                                <input type="text" wire:model="nrc" id="nrc" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                        @else
                            <div class="mb-3">
                                <label for="tipoD" class="form-label">Tipo Documento</label>
                                <select wire:model="tipoDoc" id="tipoD" class="form-select" wire:change="searchClient">
                                    <option value="DUI">DUI</option>
                                    <option value="NIT">NIT</option>
                                    <option value="Pasaporte">Pasaporte</option>
                                    <option value="Carnet de residente">Carnet de residente</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="mb-3">
                                <label for="infoField2" class="form-label">Numero de documento</label>
                                <input type="text" wire:model="infoField2" id="infoField2" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                        @endif
                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <label for="infoField3" class="form-label">Nombre</label>
                            <input type="text" wire:model="infoField3" id="infoField3" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <label for="infoField4" class="form-label">Nombre Comercial</label>
                            <input type="text" wire:model="infoField4" id="infoField4" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                        @if ($tipoDoc == 'Pasaporte' || $tipoDoc == 'Carnet de residente')
                            <div class="mb-3">
                                <label for="actividad" class="form-label">Actividad Economica</label>
                                <input type="text" wire:model="actividad" id="actividad" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                        @else
                            <div class="mb-3">
                                <label for="actividad" class="form-label">Actividad Economica</label>
                                <select wire:model="actividad" id="actividad" class="form-select">
                                    <option value="opcion1">Opción 1</option>
                                    <option value="opcion2">Opción 2</option>
                                    <option value="opcion3">Opción 3</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        @endif
    
                    </div>
                    {{-- Sección Dirección --}}
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <h3>Dirección</h3>
                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <label for="direccionField1" class="form-label">Telefono</label>
                            <input type="text" wire:model="direccionField1" id="direccionField1" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <label for="direccionField2" class="form-label">Correo Electronico</label>
                            <input type="text" wire:model="direccionField2" id="direccionField2" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                        @if ($tipoDoc == 'Pasaporte' || $tipoDoc == 'Carnet de residente')
                            <div class="mb-3">
                                <label for="pais" class="form-label">Pais</label>
                                <select wire:model="pais" id="pais" class="form-select">
                                    <option value="residencial">Residencial</option>
                                    <option value="comercial">Comercial</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        @else
                            <div class="mb-3">
                                <input type="text" wire:model="pais" id="pais" class="form-control"
                                    value="El Salvador" readonly>
                            </div>
                            <div class="mb-3">
                                <label for="depar" class="form-label">Departamento</label>
                                <select wire:model="depa" id="depar" class="form-select">
                                    @forelse ($departamentos as $departamento)
                                        <option value="{{ $departamento->CODIGO }}">{{ $departamento->DESCRIPCION }}
                                        </option>
                                    @empty
    
                                    @endforelse
    
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            {{ $depa }}
                            <div class="mb-3">
                                <label for="muni" class="form-label">Municipio</label>
                                <select wire:model="muni" id="muni" class="form-select">
                                    <option value="residencial">Residencial</option>
                                    <option value="comercial">Comercial</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        @endif
    
                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <label for="direccionField5" class="form-label">Complemento</label>
                            <input type="text" wire:model="direccionField5" id="direccionField5"
                                class="form-control">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
    
                {{-- Sección Exportación --}}
                <div class="mb-4 row">
                    <div class="offset-md-3 col-md-6">
                        <h3>Exportación</h3>
                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <label for="exportacionField1" class="form-label">Actividad economica exportacion</label>
                            <input type="text" wire:model="exportacionField1" id="exportacionField1"
                                class="form-control">
                        </div>
                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <label for="exportacionField2" class="form-label">Correo electronico exportacion</label>
                            <input type="text" wire:model="exportacionField2" id="exportacionField2"
                                class="form-control">
                        </div>
                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <label for="exportacionField3" class="form-label">Telefono exportacion</label>
                            <input type="text" wire:model="exportacionField3" id="exportacionField3"
                                class="form-control">
                        </div>
                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <label for="exportacionField4" class="form-label">Complemento direccion exportacion</label>
                            <input type="text" wire:model="exportacionField4" id="exportacionField4"
                                class="form-control">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
    
                <div class="d-grid">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Enviar</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Modelo:

```
    <?php

namespace App\Livewire\Clientes;

use App\Models\Catalogo;
use App\Models\Cliente;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use Livewire\Component;

class ClientesForm extends Component
{
    public $search;
    public $tipoDoc = "DUI";
    public $tipoPersona = 1;
    public $departamentos;
    public $municipios;
    public $depa = '01';
    public function render()
    {
        //
        //$this->municipios();
        return view('livewire.clientes.clientes-form');
    }
    public function mount()
    {
        $this->departamentos();
    }
    public function searchClient()
    {
        if (!$this->search == "") {
            $cliente = Cliente::find($this->search) ?: new Cliente();
            $this->tipoPersona = $cliente->TIPO_PERSONA;
        } else {
        }
        $this->search = "";
    }

    public function departamentos()
    {
        try {
            $this->departamentos = Catalogo::select('CODIGO', 'DESCRIPCION')
                ->where('PADRE_ID', Catalogo::select('ID')
                    ->where('CODIGO', 'CAT-012'))->get() ?: new Catalogo();;
        } catch (\Throwable $th) {
            log::error($th);
        }
    }

    public function municipios()
    {
        try {
            $this->municipios = Catalogo::select('CODIGO', 'DESCRIPCION')->where('PADRE_ID', Catalogo::select('ID')->where('CODIGO', 'CAT-013'))
                ->where('AUXILIAR', $this->depa)->get() ?: new Catalogo();
        } catch (\Throwable $th) {
            log::error($th);
        }
    }
}
```

Cabe recalcar que estoy usando laravel 9, livewire 3.0 y eloquent

Answer (score 0):

en primer lugar veo que Tenes enlazadas muchas propiedades que no existen o no están definidas en tu controlador

```
    wire:model="exportacionField1"
    wire:model="infoField3"
    wire:model="infoField4"
```

no existe la propiedad en tu controlador

deberia ser algo asi

```
    public $exportacionField1;
```

hay varias por toda tu vista

fijate un poco por ahi.

segundo podrias ver si realmente funciona el query de departamentos y municipios

revisando lo que trae con la funcion dd()

ejemplo

```
    $this->departamentos = Catalogo::select('CODIGO', 'DESCRIPCION')
    ->where('PADRE_ID', Catalogo::select('ID')
    ->where('CODIGO', 'CAT-012'))->get() ?: new Catalogo();;

    dd($this->departamentos);
```

ahi vas a ver si realmente el query trae algo

tercero en la linea del query de departamentos hay dos puntos y comas (;;)
puede estar el error ahí

espero que te ayude.

saludos

Answer (score 0):

Parece un problema de que necesita una ejecutar una función para que se guarde el contenido en la variable mediante wire:model, como una solución poco atractiva, pero que funciona, es designarle una función que solo tenga un return para activar el wire:model y que se guarden los datos, de la siguiente manera:

Al input le agregas un wire:keyup, cada vez que se levante una tecla, se ejecuta un return⬇️ que seria la función update

< input type="text" wire:model="titleNote" wire:keyup="update" >

Y esta es la función update a la que apuntamos con el wire:keyup⬇️

```
public function update()
{
    return;
}
```

Quizá no es la manera más correcta de solucionarlo, pero es una solución rápida